# How to sort a TableView programmatically?

Tags: java, javafx

I want a certain column of a `TableView` to be sorted by default. How would I do this? I tried doing `column.setSortType(SortType.ASCENDING);`, as well as putting it in a `runLater` call. I looked at the JavaDocs and stuff and all I can see that may be of interest is the peculiar `setSortPolicy` method.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To perform a "one-off" sort, call

```
tableView.getSortOrder().setAll(...);
```

passing in the `TableColumn`(s) by which you want the data sorted.

To make the sort persist even as the items in the list change, create a [`SortedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/transformation/SortedList.html) and pass it to the table's `setItems(...)` method. (To change the items, you will still manipulate the underlying list.)

As an example, using the usual [contact table example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/table-view.htm#CJAGAAEE) you could do:

```
TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();
TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameCol = new TableColumn<>("First Name");
firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().firstNameProperty());
TableColumn<Person, String> lastNameCol = new TableColumn<>("
Last Name");
firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().lastNameProperty());

ObservableList<Person> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

SortedList<Person> sortedData = new SortedList<>(data);

// this ensures the sortedData is sorted according to the sort columns in the table:
sortedData.comparatorProperty().bind(table.comparatorProperty());

table.setItems(sortedData);

// programmatically set a sort column:
table.getSortOrder().addAll(firstNameCol);

// note that you should always manipulate the underlying list, not the sortedList:
data.addAll(new Person(...), new Person(...));
```

Comment: This works...kind of. I can sort the table originally, but when I change the items in it, the sort is cleared. I also cannot change the sort order by hand from the front-end.

Comment: To enable sorting to persist through changes to the items, set the items to a [`SortedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/transformation/SortedList.html) (and manipulate the underlying list). Added that to the answer; if you need more details you probably need to provide code in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Called at the end of the table initialisation...

```
colChecked.setSortType(TreeTableColumn.SortType.DESCENDING);
colDate.setSortType(TreeTableColumn.SortType.DESCENDING);
treeView.getSortOrder().setAll(colChecked, colDate);
```